# automate java desktop application actions

Tags: java, swing, desktop-application

I developed a java desktop application where the user can manually load a file and press a button to start a simulation process. I want to automate the above two steps so that an external program can iteratively call this desktop application multiple times and run the simulation process without any human intervention every time. Any thoughts on how I can go about doing this?

Comment: Maybe your answer is here: [old question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16411823/junit-tests-for-gui-in-java

Comment: Use the program arguments (`String[] args`) to specify one or more files to process. Don't show the filechooser when at least one valid argument is given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which OS you do it.

If OS X, use [automator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automator_%28software%29), for Windows you can use [winautomation](http://www.winautomation.com) and for Linux use google and search (for example) `kde automation`.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question. But there is a new solution now,
[JAuto](https://heshiming.github.io/jauto/): a [JVMTI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html) agent that runs in Java VM and expose UI widget attributes such as class names, screen coordinates. You talk to JAuto by sending a command to a named pipe. It responds by writing a file. It lets you control a Java program via [bash scripts](https://heshiming.github.io/jauto/faq.html#how-do-i-call-jauto-in-a-bash-script).

Using an input simulator such as [xdotool](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool), you can achieve automation under the Linux X11 settings.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of JAuto.